# File doesn't exist, will create

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I'm seeing the following errors in the system settings on iOS fit the Stack Exchange app. I can only assume it is a bug.

I am using an iPhone 6 plus running iOS 8.1.1

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yup, it's a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had a problem here with the script that creates the acknowledgements section. A file managed by CocoaPods was moved, but the script wasn't updated to reflect that change. Should be fixed beginning in **beta version 1.2.0.174**.